# Adding a Hyperlink in Excel 2007 With Domain in Different Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, hyperlink

I want to add a hyperlink in a cell, but getting the domain from a different cell.

For example:

```
A1 = localhost
B3 = http://(A1)/test.htm
```

So I can change `A1` to point to an IP address.

Is this possible in Excel 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`B3` => `=hyperlink("http://" & A1 &"/test.html")`
... tested - does work in LibreOffice. *You need to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click on it...*

Comment: Much work in Excel can be handled as text, with subsequent action on it, :-)